# Write large data to file caching issue

Tags: file, caching, c#-4.0

I have a problem when I write a large amount of data <2GB to a file. First ~1.4GB data are written fast (100 MB/s) than the code become really slow (0-2 MB/s).

My code (simplified) is:

```
//FileOptions FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING = (FileOptions)0x20000000;
    FileOptions fileOptions = FileOptions.SequentialScan;

    int fileBufferSize = 1024 * 1024;
    byte[] Buffer = new byte[32768];

    Random random = new Random();
    long fileSize = 2588490188;
    long totalByteWritten = 0;

    using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"c:\test\test.bin", fileBufferSize, fileOptions))
    {
        while (totalByteWritten < fileSize)
        {
            random.NextBytes(Buffer);
            fs.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
            totalByteWritten += Buffer.Length;
            //Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

I think there is an issue related to caching problem, in fact during "fast write performance" RAM used increase as well, when RAM usage stop to increase there is a drop in performance.

What I have tried:

- change to async write
  ->no significantly change
- change array buffer size
  ->no significantly change
- change `fileBufferSize`
  ->no significantly change, but with a large buffer ~100MB, write performance is fast and when RAM usage stop to increase, write performance goes to 0 and than, after a while, goes back to 100MB, it seams that cache buffer is "flushed"
- change `fileOption` to `WriteThrough`
  ->performance are always slow..
- adding after xx loops `fs.Flush(true)`
  ->no significantly change
- uncomment `Thread.Sleep(10)`
  ->write speed is always good.....this is strange

Comment: it seems like the thread.sleep is helping the memory to get cleared and dumped to disk. can you do a benchmark of your hd write speed? i think that at start everything is written to memory, until it is full and then both the windows paging file is being written (since you maxed the memory) and your file continues writing, so the performance is getting low. but i might be wrong :)

Comment: Any chance there is some anti-virus software running on the system that slows down performance after RAM is filled and data starts getting written to disk?

Comment: Hm, to my understanding ´FileOptions.SequentialScan´ has no use at all in your scenario. This would be important when *reading* from disc not writing. As far as I understood, this is only a simplified code snippet, so I guess the ´random.NextBytes´ is only a placeholder for you real data. Where does the real data come from? Could collecting the real data be the culprit?

Comment: I'll check the hd write speed. And NO Antivirus, I have made the same test after removing the antivirus. Real data are comming from a gigabit ethernet or from some analysis of a large file, random.NextBytes is used only as random data generator

Answer (score 0):

Is it somehow trying to write before it's finished writing the previous chunk and getting in a mess? (seems unlikely, but it's very odd that the `Thread.Sleep` should speed it up and this might explain it). What happens if you modify the code inside the using statement to lock the filestream, like this?

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(@"c:\testing\test.bin", fileBufferSize, fileOptions))
{
  while (fs.Position < fileBufferSize)
  {
    lock(fs) // this is the bit I have added to try to speed it up
    {
      random.NextBytes(Buffer);
      fs.Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: I have tweaked your example code to include the while loop required to make it write a file of the correct size.

Incidentally, when I run the sample code it is very quick with or without the `lock` statement and adding the sleep slows it down significantly.